# winpcap on linux

Tags: linux, winpcap

I am trying to port an Windows executable to Linux using wine. I am at a point where I can run the executables but it returns some error saying it can't load "npf" driver. Is there a way to also port winpcap on Linux? The application I was trying to port is depending on winpcap library.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

libpcap? It is the original version of pcap that was then made into winpcap...

Comment: But the application I wanted to port to Linux only knows about winpap. If I have the source code, I might be able to changes the APIs, but I only have the executable.

Answer (score 1):

winpcap depends on the custom Windows drivers to provide access to the raw streams, it's not possible to port that as-is to wine.

Comment: so there is no way for me to port that application, which depends on winpcap, to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

winpcap is essentially a set of a Windows driver and two DLL's, wich enables applications to send&receive raw network packets to&from the network cards, and originally was a tool to have the same features than tcdump in Uxix/Linux in WIndows.
So, maybe a solution a wrapper in Linux of the "libpcap(capture) and libnet(send)" libraries, providing a winpcap binary compatibility? Playonlinux guys can help?